# renderInContext / Memory problem

Tags: memory, memory-management

I have a problem. When I use the "renderInContext" in the iPad, the used memory is never released and accumulates until the application closes with "Memory Warning" Level=1 and Level=2

My code:

```
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 16.54 * 72.0, 24.02 * 72.0);
            CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:posterPath isDirectory:NO], &mediaBox, NULL);
            CGPDFContextBeginPage(ctx, NULL);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 0.516, -0.516);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -mediaBox.size.height - 1500);
            [[self returnBigView].layer renderInContext:ctx];
            CGPDFContextEndPage(ctx);
            CGPDFContextClose(ctx);
            CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

I have tried several ways, but no free memory. Any ideas?

** Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too, inside a loop - setting the layer contents to nil worked for me:

[Releasing renderInContext result within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970627/releasing-renderincontext-result-within-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  After a long investigation, it seems the memory was not released because the code did not run on the main thread.  So don't execute renderInContext when you're not working on the main thread!